# Saving JPEG to database

Tags: delphi

This code give Access violation at the TBlobField line:

```
procedure TfrmCapture.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  j: TJPEGImage;
  S: TFileStream;
begin
  J := TJPEGImage.Create;
  try
    J.Assign(Image1.Picture.Graphic);
    J.CompressionQuality := 80;
    J.Compress;
    J.SaveToStream(S);
    S.Position := 0;
    TBlobField(frmSignout.tblImg.FieldByName('Picture')).LoadFromStream(S);
  finally
    J.Free;
  end;
  Image1.Picture := nil;
  Close;
end;
```

Basically Im trying to convert a Timage into JPEG and then save it to Image field (MSSQL express)
any ideas how to fix it ?

Comment: Just realized that the stream might be empty and then it trows the Access violation ...is that possible ? I can assign the stream to Image2 and it shows up with no problem.

Comment: Ever heard of `TFileStream.Create` e.g.`S := TFileStream.Create('c:\test.dat', fmOpenReadWrite);`

Comment: How did you manage to get this code block highlighted while simultaneously losing the indentation? o_0

Comment: Man whats wrong with me it has to be MemoryStream not FileStream..and I wasted an hour trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 5):

You are not instantiating the `TFileStream` that you save to:

```
procedure TfrmCapture.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 J: TJPEGImage;
 S: TFileStream;
begin
  J := TJPEGImage.Create;
  try
    J.Assign(Image1.Picture.Graphic);
    J.CompressionQuality := 80;
    J.Compress;
    S := TFileStream.Create('c:\path to\somefile.jpg', fmCreate); // <-- add this!
    try
      J.SaveToStream(S);
      S.Position := 0;
      TBlobField(frmSignout.tblImg.FieldByName('Picture')).LoadFromStream(S);
    finally
      S.Free; // <-- add this
    end;
  finally
    J.Free;
  end;
  Image1.Picture := nil;
  Close;
end;
```

That being said, I would suggest avoiding the file altogether (unless you really need it) and use `TDataSet.CreateBlobStream()` instead of `TBlobField.LoadFromStream()`:

```
procedure TfrmCapture.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 J: TJPEGImage;
 S: TStream;
begin
  J := TJPEGImage.Create;
  try
    J.Assign(Image1.Picture.Graphic);
    J.CompressionQuality := 80;
    J.Compress;
    S := frmSignout.tlbImg.CreateBlobStream(frmSignout.tblImg.FieldByName('Picture'), bmWrite); 
    try
      J.SaveToStream(S);
    finally
      S.Free;
    end;
  finally
    J.Free;
  end;
  Image1.Picture := nil;
  Close;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Man Im just tired...of course its not file stream its memory stream..jeez.

This is the correct code to save Timage as JPEG in MSSQL express (~50kb/image):

```
procedure TfrmCapture.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
j:TJPEGImage;
S : TMemorystream;
begin
J := TJPEGImage.Create;
S := Tmemorystream.Create;
try
J.Assign(image1.Picture.graphic);
J.CompressionQuality :=80;
J.Compress;
J.SaveToStream(S);
S.Position :=0;
(frmSignout.tblImg.FieldByName('Picture') as TblobField).LoadFromStream(S);
finally
J.Free;
S.Free;
end;
image1.Picture :=nil;
close;
end;
```

Comment: @Sardukar: you should have posted this as an edit to the original question, not posted as a separate answer.

Comment: O I see..I thought I should leave the error for educational purposes..